# C# Namespace 'ServiceModel' does not exist in namespace 'System'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

I have been searching the forum for answers to my problem but unfortunately the proposed solutions have not worked for me.
I have a project (Classes library .NET Framework) with the reference to the System.ServiceModel assembly added. In fact, if that reference the code fails. I add an image where you can see the added reference:

[image]

Now, I want to catch the FaultException exception and when I add:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
```

I can't compile and I get the error:

Namespace 'ServiceModel' does not exist in namespace 'System'.

Just in case I deleted the reference and added it again but the problem persists.
I must be missing something but I can't figure out what it could be.
Could someone help me? I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
Thank you very much!

Comment: It's difficult to diagnose from a screenshot. Does your solution contain more than one project? If so, have you added the reference to the right project? These are questions we can't answer since we can't scroll that solution explorer window.

Comment: What version of .NET Framework?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I looked several times and I didn't notice what you say, the solution has two projects, the library itself (where the reference was added) and a console application for testing (here the reference was missing). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I didn't see the problem @Damien_The_Unbeliever commented on. Adding the reference in the other project solved my problem!